# Proof help for an graph-algebraic proof that for all $n\ge 5$ there exists a tournament graph that has maximum distance $2$

Tags: algebraic-graph-theory

Let $G=(V,E)$ be a graph with $|V|=n$ nodes, and the property for all  pairs of nodes $a,b\in V, a\neq b$ we have precisely one edge, i.e. either $a\to b$ or $b\to a$.
This type of graph is called a [tournament](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tournament_(graph_theory)), as it depicts the outcome of a round-robin tournament of $n$ players.

I've tried myself at a algebraic-graph-theory proof that for all $n\ge 5$ we can construct a graph $G$ as above so that the maximum distance between any two nodes is 2.

(The regular proof brute-forces $n=1,..,6$ and finds that $n=3,5,6$ work, then uses induction to show that if we have a graph $G=(V,E)$ that works for $n$ , we can build one for $n+2$ by 
adding the vertices $v_1,v_2$ to it, and adding the edges $v_1→v_2$, and $v→v_1,v_2→v$ for all nodes $v\in V\setminus\{v_1,v_2\}$ )

Now to the algebraic-proof-theory proof on which I got stuck:

Let $L$ be the adjacency-matrix representation of $G$, then we find the following equality:
$$
L + L^T +I= {1}
$$
(where $1$ shall mean the matrix that has a $1$ in all cells$, and $I$ is the identity matrix)

We now have to show that  all cells in $L^2 + L +I$ are $\ge 1$ 
(as $L$ is the adjacency matrix representation of $G$, $(L^k)_{i,j}$ tells us how many paths of length $k$ there are from node $i$ to node $j$)

We start by doing some algebraic transformations. Let $L_{\downarrow i}$ depict the $i$-th column of $L$. Then we have:

$$\begin{align}
L^2 + L + I &= (1-L^T-I)L + L +I=  (1-L^T)L + I \\
&= \pmatrix{1\\...\\1}(1,..,1)L - L^TL  +I
\\
&= \pmatrix{\sum L_{\downarrow1}& ...&\sum L_{\downarrow n}
\\\vdots&\vdots&\vdots\\
\sum L_{\downarrow1}& ...&\sum L_{\downarrow n}} -L^T L +I
\\
&= \pmatrix{\sum L_{\downarrow1}& ...&\sum L_{\downarrow n}
\\\vdots&\vdots&\vdots\\
\sum L_{\downarrow1}& ...&\sum L_{\downarrow n}}
- (L_{\downarrow i}^T L_{\downarrow j})_{i=1,...,n\\j=1,..,n}+I
\\
&= \pmatrix{\sum L_{\downarrow1}- L_{\downarrow 1}^T L_{\downarrow 1}& ...&\sum L_{\downarrow n}  - L_{\downarrow 1}^T L_{\downarrow n}
\\\vdots&\vdots&\vdots\\
\sum L_{\downarrow1}- L_{\downarrow n}^T L_{\downarrow 1}& ...&\sum L_{\downarrow n} - L_{\downarrow n}^T L_{\downarrow n}}
+I
\end{align} 
$$

Our goal is to find a way to choose $L$ so that each cell is $\ge 1$.

For the diagonal we have $\sum L_{\downarrow i} - L_{\downarrow i}L_{\downarrow i} + 1 = 1\quad$ (with the $1$ coming from $I$).

So, if we can show that $\sum L_{\downarrow i} - L_{\downarrow i}L_{\downarrow j}\ge 1$ for all $j\neq i, j=1,..,n$, we are done.

We can rewrite each cell as:
$$
\sum L_{\downarrow i} - L_{\downarrow i}^TL_{\downarrow j} 
\\= 
(1,...,1) L_{\downarrow i} - L_{\downarrow i}^TL_{\downarrow j}
\\=
\big((1,...,1)  - L_{\downarrow i}^T \big)L_{\downarrow j}
$$

This means that if we can choose the entries of $L$ so that for every ordered pair of columns of $L$ we have one row that is $0$ in the first, and $1$ in the second column, we are done.

(i.e. if the columns are $ L_{\downarrow i},L_{\downarrow j}, \,\, i,j\in\{1,..,n\}, i\neq j$ they'll have to look like $\pmatrix{...\\1\\...},\pmatrix{...\\0\\...}$ or equivalently $L_{k,i} = 1, L_{k,j} =0$)

And that's the point where I'm stuck. I can't think of a way that makes use of this property while also taking the special shape of $L$